# Backbone JS not very jQuery like?

Tags: javascript-framework, backbone.js, prototypal-inheritance

Backbone JS highly recommends you use jQuery.  However, it doesn't do things very jQuery.  For example, jQuery removes the necessity of the new operator, backbone makes heavy use of it.

On another note, I'm looking for a framework that is based more around prototypal inheritance than classical inheritance (new).  jQuery doesn't fall under this category, this is just an architecture style I am leaning towards.

Are there any frameworks that use prototypal inheritance, or is it roll your own bridge pattern?

Comment: As I understand it, Backbone recommends using jQuery because the two libraries compliment each other well - not necessarily anything to do with the "style" of the library. _Full disclaimer: I am not a Backbone JS guy._

Comment: jQuery is only necessary if you don't write your own library for handling the DOM and native events. Unfortunately, not many jQuery developers will be able to pick up the concepts of backbone without a background in a formal language. jQuery is great for quickly adding widgets to a HTML page but lacks as building tool for creating applications.

Comment: I get what you're saying, but this question isn't posed in a way that's easy to answer.  At first you're comparing the development styles of jQuery and Backbone, but you don't really ask a question.  Then you go on to ask about prototypal inheritance, which seems to have little to do with the title of your question.

Comment: Just discovered an MVC library that may suite your (and possibly my) JS coding style: [Stapes.js](http://hay.github.com/stapes/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Backbone and jQuery solve different problems... Backbone essentially gives you a structure in order to make Javascript heavy apps... It gives you Models, Collections, Views and Controllers (although, based on only a day of playing with it, it feels to me like controllers are used for routing, and the views are kind of like a classic controller)

Backbone has a dependency on jQuery (or Zepto if you're that way inclined) to help it do things like AJAX requests.

You are correct - it is not very jQuery like, but it is providing you with something very different...

---

**UPDATE**

As of version 0.5.0 backbone have renamed controllers to routers, which should make things a little more obvious for folks coming from MS MVC / Rails etc...

*"We've taken the opportunity to clarify some naming with the 0.5.0 release. Controller is now Router"*

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router

Comment: Re: Update, apparently controllers were removed entirely.

Answer (score 4):

I fully agree with the answer provided by Paul and also would like to restate that your question is ambiguous in its essentials.

Jquery is highly dom-centric and provides you excellent facilities for operating upon the DOM. Be it changing styles, loading remote content to some portion of document, responding to browser events ... in (almost) everything the core focus is upon the DOM. For this kind of functionality, where you are operating upon document content, prototypal inheritance and more significantly the style of accessing widgets through the DOM (check out the APIs of JQueryUI) works rather well. If you identify widgets as javascript objects, then you have to keep track of the objects as well ... which you in case of the programming style followed by JQueryUI etc., you dont have to, because you can access any widget present in the DOM by navigating through the DOM structure or simply through its id (which essentially acts as a global identifier for the element).

backbone.js is altogether built for a different purpose. The very introduction clearly states that it is built upon the underlying philosophy that tying your data to the DOM is bad. 
When you build an application that structured as per backbone.js conventions, you are essentially always concentrated on javascript objects which may be *somehow* linked to the DOM. 
You are defining models that interface with server data sources, models which trigger events when the data contents are manipulated, collections which help you manage large data sets ... whatever, you are always operating on javascript objects which are not hardwired into the Document structure. For such scenario, it is more usual to think in terms of traditional object oriented model. 
Once you have an object, the workflow is not much different from what you are habituated with using jQuery because backbone too, just like jQuery, advocates for the observer pattern. 
So, in the same manner that you can bind event handlers to DOM elements with JQuery, you attach event handlers to custom events dispatched by models, collectors etc. So the two amalgamate well.

As far as other frameworks are concerned, you might want to checkout Knockout which provides data bindings and observables etc. and does not require you to use new keyword to create instances, rather instances are created by calling functions in ko namespace which might appeal to your tastes. KO has extensive documentation and code examples, which you can explore to decide whether it suites your tastes. I can not comment more on KO because I have limited knowledge about it, but as far as backbone.js is concerned I would very strongly recommend you not to dismiss the framework just because you dont like the way some things are implemented. It does elegantly and robustly what it is supposed to do and maintains an incredibly small footprint.

Answer (score 2):

I think you suffer from a misunderstanding of prototypal inheritance and what you actually want in a framework.  If you're modifying prototypes but never using the `new` keyword, then you're never creating new objects. If you're looking for a framework to abstract away object creation, that's another topic, though you shouldn't be afraid to use the `new` keyword; It's a big part of JavaScript.

You can actually use the `new` syntax with jQuery, and when you don't use it, jQuery is actually recalling itself again with the `new` syntax along with the arguments you passed to it. This is pure syntactic sugar and makes very little difference about anything.

"On another note, I'm looking for a framework that is based more around prototypal inheritance than classical inheritance (new)."

Backbone is built on prototypal inheritance through the method `extend` that is built into all models, collections, and views. It's quite problem free and easier to use and adds things like `super` - a hook into the parent's prototype - something that can be more difficult to do with just plain JS prototyping.

Comment: Whether `new` is essential depends on how you see it. With `Object.create` the `new` keyword becomes obsolete. In fact I consider `new` to be ugly and confusing. Beautiful article on the topic: [Understanding “Prototypes” in JavaScript](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

Backbone.js brings a codding standard for ajax driven web-apps that don't have to refresh the page in order to serve data.

jQuery brings a set of tools to help you get basic things done without worrying about the browser you're running the code in.

They have nothing in common. It's like comparing a hammer (jQuery) with a toolbox (backbone.js). The hammer is just a part of the toolbox, not the other way around.

So, yes! Backbone.js is not like jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

> "I'm looking for a framework that is based more around prototypal
>   inheritance than classical inheritance the new operator".

There is no 'classical' inheritance on Javascript. Actually there is no other standard way to prototype than using 'new' maybe jQuery just provides a method who does the 'new' inside.

```
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
},
```

Comment: Object.create https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create/

Comment: Correction: Standard and multibroser way (including IE8)